# Modify jQueryUI datepicker buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

The jQueryUI datepicker can be setup with a Today and Done button.  See http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#buttonbar.

How can I trigger some event (i.e. `alert('close');`) whenever the Done button is clicked, and then continue with the buttons default functionality (i.e. closing the calender).

Note that I do not wish to use the `onClose()` method as this is triggered when the calender is closed through any means (i.e. clicking off the calender), and not necessarily when the Done button is clicked.

PS.  I don't think it is relevant, but I am using the datepicker in connection with http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a separate handler by using event delegation.

```
$(document).on('click', 'button.ui-datepicker-close', function(){
    alert('close')
});
```

I bound the event handler to the `Done` button as it's not entirely clear what behavior you want although I think this is what you are asking

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ogj9v5ac/)**</kbd>

Comment: Thanks Charlie,  This totally does what I asked, however, I probably should have been more specific.  I need access the calender `this` object.  I suppose I could do it this way, and directly access the calender ID?

Comment: can access it through the API. What exactly are you needing?

Comment: I suppose just binding another event works.  Would be curious on how to access it via the API.

Comment: well if you need date for example use the `getDate` method http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-getDate

Comment: So, there is no event that triggers when the done button is clicked other than onclose?

Comment: probably not, but you could also call  a custom event from `onclose` callback but you said you dind't want that (not sure why though)

Comment: I currently am doing a custom event from `onclose`, and checking if the date has changes and acting accordingly.  Not very clean, but it seems to work.  Appreciate the help.

Comment: don't see why it isn't clean, event callbacks are exposed for a reason